# Trying to copy a column range on on sheet and paste it in a row on a different sheet and have it inserted to top with each time the script runs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy a column range on on sheet and paste it in a row on a different sheet. I want it inserted to the top each time the script runs. This is what I got so far:

```
function Copy() {

 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1UbcIcGJRVxsX9WbzunS96Ijf8c2gRc8UYb40lHpWWQU'); //source ID

 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Container Input'); //source Sheet tab name

 var range = ss.getRange('B4:B23'); //assigned range to copy

 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1UbcIcGJRVxsX9WbzunS96Ijf8c2gRc8UYb40lHpWWQU'); //destination ID

 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Container Log'); //destination sheet tab name

 ts.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data); //you will need to define the size of the copied data see getRange()

//range.clearContent(); //clears var range

}
```

Answer (score 0):

function Copy()
{

var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1UbcIcGJRVxsX9WbzunS96Ijf8c2gRc8UYb40lHpWWQU'); 
 //source ID

var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Container Input'); //source Sheet tab name

var ts = sss.getSheetByName('Cylinder Tracking'); //destination sheet tab name

//var protection = ts.protect();

//protection.setUnprotectedRanges(2,1,1,21);

ts.insertRowsBefore(2, 1);// Adds a new row before row 2 - Keeps the formatting of the 
 old row 2 for the new row 2

var source_C = 2;

var source_R = 3;

var dest_C = 2;

var dest_R = 2;

SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Cylinder Tracking!A2').setValue(new Date())
  for (var counter = 1; counter <= 20; counter++)
  {

var source_range = ss.getRange(source_R,source_C); //assigned range to copy

var data = source_range.getValues();

var dest_range = ss.getRange(dest_C,dest_R);

ts.getRange(dest_R, dest_C).setValues(data); //you will need to define the size of the 
  copied data see getRange()

source_R++;

dest_C++;

}
}